# skypeFailed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadRequest: Can't create new Teams Channel via

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've created many Teams channels with Graph without any problems. Now after a few weeks of successful use, my application stopped working at this feature. I called the API with Graph Explorer and it comes up with the same error:

POST:

```
/beta/groups/{groupid}/team/channels
```

REQUEST:

```
{
  "displayName": "Test112",
  "description": "Test1142"
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message":
      "Channel thread creation failed for team thread id 19:7f795d63412840318ead600f45dd4dac@thread.skypeFailed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadRequest.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a56cd318-87bf-4393-994f-bcd46e0c00b3",
      "date": "2018-06-18T06:12:35"
    }
  }
}
```

I am member and owner of the team/group. I tried it for many other teams. The behavior is very irregular: Sometimes it works, sometimes it works only after waiting some time and trying again.

Has anyone an idea, why this happens? Currently, I can't understand the problem or the pattern behind this issue.

Comment: Are you creating multiple channels in a loop? Is it working for after some interval for the same Team?

Comment: Could you please also share TenantId & Team Id for which you call is failing?

Comment: Only one channel at a time. 
I made the experience that it works directly after creating the new team. It stops working irregularly some time after team creation. Sometimes it works after waiting a few days but not every time.

Comment: Tenant-Id: a3c5cc50-4c46-40c9-a085-0aa8b315f94d
Team/Group-Id: 4d0d23d7-7ed3-4bc0-a411-040d7624bba9

Comment: Could you please try to repro this and share the request/response for failed case once more?

Comment: POST: `/teams/{id}/channels`

REQUEST: `{
  "displayName": "Test112",
  "description": "Test1142"
}`

RESPONSE: `{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadRequest.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6a7df57f-d159-4b9d-bb04-6b490e12413d",
            "date": "2018-06-29T14:47:44"
        }
    }
} `
groupId: ddaeec19-8824-4a15-b4ef-6d97a43d4706

The before mentioned groupId 4d0d23d7-7ed3-4bc0-a411-040d7624bba9 now works fine. We did not change anything here.

Comment: This can happen if the user is not a part of the team. Can you confirm that the user is trying to get channels for the team that he is a part of?

Comment: Yes, the user is owner and member of the team that he is trying to post channels to.

Comment: As you mentioned earlier that channel creation is working on/off. Is this happening for same user X?

Comment: Could you please share the request/response if you see the failure?

Comment: Yes, it happens to the same user. We tested it with another user and it behaves similar (on/off).

Comment: Could you please share the recently failed request/response?

Comment: POST: `teams/{id}/channels` REQUEST: `{displayName: "FR-SG-2018-0008", description: "FR-SG-2018-0008"}` RESPONSE: `{
  "error": {
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "Channel thread creation failed for team thread id 19:83270a1ccb5c4cf88e5b8de977efeb19@thread.skypeFailed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadRequest.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bef103f8-0a9a-4b17-be52-0a0e884d87e6",
      "date": "2018-07-06T16:42:43"
    }
  }
}`

GroupId: 0970a21e-b1b0-40b8-8d47-a5c84ae19ed4

Comment: Could you please share the team settings for the last request? Is user calling create channel api owner of this team?

Comment: Could you please also share both failed and successful requests/response for the same team?